# Prove a set is measurable with induction process

Tags: real-analysis

I have a set $\Omega_n=\{(x_1,x_2,......,x_n) \in R^n: x_i \ge0 , \sum x_i \le 1\}$ .

I have to prove mis$_n(\Omega_n)$=${1 \over n!}$.

Can I use the math induction?

Comment: What is mis_n? ${}$

Comment: Peano Jordan  measure